# JTable Manipulation using Vectors

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm just new to using a JTable and we have an activity of using such, I got a problem in making my table in which it doesn't have a single table cell in it.
[image]
I just want to know if there is a way in creating a cell in it without adding a value.
Im using a vector for my table data by the way.

> PS: My Teacher forbids us from using Arrays that's why I use vector instead coz that's the only thing I can find easy for me to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to add empty cell to JTable. you can do it with adding row with empty vector.

```
model.addRow(new Vector());
```

if it is still not clear.  create a model

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
        String[] person = {"ID", "firstName", "LastName", "M.I", "Age", "Street", "City"};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return person.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int index) {
            return person[index];
        }
    };
```

add empty row

```
model.addRow(new Vector()); // your empty vector
```

pass model to Jtable constructor

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

and it will display table with empty row in it. 
[image]

if you do not know what is model and how to use them. check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) link.